# Memory alloc issues, crash on device iOS SDK 4.1(Thread 0 crash)

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, device, nsautoreleasepool

I have two problems

1) My App works fine on the device the first few times its run. Then it crashes after the First screen pops up(Tab BAr). If i connect the device to my MAC and then run the device app it works(not debug mode).

I Checked the crash Logs, it crashed cos of "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)" and Thread0 crashed.The error was NSAutorelease released a deallocated Object.

2) I ran the app using instruments on the simulator. It show a lot of leaks on this function call. 
Here is a sample code. When i run it using Instruments it shows a leak on the "setObject" line.

//class A- subclass of NSObject

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)Hello {

 NSMutableDictionary *dctONE = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:0];
 NSMutableArray *arrKeys = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

    [arrKeys addObject:@"Object1"];
 [arrKeys addObject:@"Object2"];

    [dctONE setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dsfsdf"] forKey:[arrKeys          objectAtIndex:0]];
 [dctONE setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"dsfsdf"] forKey:[arrKeys objectAtIndex:1]];

    [arrKeys release];
    return dctONE;

}
```

/// class B

```
-(void)some_Function {
 NSMutableDictionary * dct = [A Hello];   //all declarations are done

 //do stuff with dct
 [dct release];
}
```

WHy does it Leak at "setObject"?? I am releasing everything properly right? Only thing is the [NSString stringWithFormat:] but that is autorelease right??

This is driving me Crazy?

Are the two problems related??
PS: It Doesnt crash on the sim, and strangely doesnt crash even when i connect my device to my MAC and then test it on device(not debugging, directly clicking the app on the device)

**EDIT:**

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *) ExecuteDataSet:(NSString *)strQuery
{
    NSMutableDictionary  *dctResult = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
//  BOOL isSucess = FALSE;

const char *sql = [strQuery UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;

//prepare the select statement
int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectStatement, NULL);
if(returnValue == SQLITE_OK)
{
    sqlite3_bind_text(selectStatement, 1, sql, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    //loop all the rows returned by the query.
    NSMutableArray *arrColumns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(selectStatement); i++) 
    {
        const char *st = sqlite3_column_name(selectStatement, i);
        [arrColumns addObject:[NSString stringWithCString:st encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    int intRow =1;
    while(sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *dctRow = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for (int i=0; i<sqlite3_column_count(selectStatement); i++)                 
        {
            int intValue = 0;
            const char *strValue;
            switch (sqlite3_column_type(selectStatement,i)) 
            {
                case SQLITE_INTEGER:
                    intValue  = (int)sqlite3_column_int(selectStatement, i);
                    [dctRow setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",intValue] forKey:[arrColumns objectAtIndex:i]];                      
                    break;

                case SQLITE_TEXT:
                    strValue = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, i);
                    [dctRow setObject:[NSString stringWithCString:strValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:[arrColumns objectAtIndex:i]];                     
                    break;

                default:
                    strValue = (const char *)sqlite3_column_value(selectStatement, i);
                    [dctRow setObject:[NSString stringWithCString:strValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forKey:[arrColumns objectAtIndex:i]];
                    break;
            }

        }
        [dctResult setObject:[dctRow retain] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Table%d",intRow]];
        intRow ++;
        [dctRow release];
    }
    [arrColumns release];
}
return dctResult;
```

}

Comment: Avoid returning retained objects, it's an open door to memory leaks.

Comment: But i release the returned object in the function that made the call. Is it not good enough? IF no how do i return a Allocated Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leak appears to be in this line:

```
[dctResult setObject:[dctRow retain] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Table%d",intRow]];
```

`setObject` will call `retain` on the object it stores, but you are actually retaining it manually, so its retain count will be 2 instead of 1, and when `dctResult` gets released, it won't be removed from memory.

Comment: Ok, so any idea why "Leaks" says that [dctOne setObject:] is a "retain" and i am not releasing it.

Comment: Also if i release it via the "caller" its not wrong right? And also any thoughts on my first Problem. the device crash??

Comment: Based on your error, it seems that you are manually calling `release` on an object that is in an autorelease pool, then, when the pool calls `release` it triggers the error. You can try enabling NSZombies to track down the problem, and see what deallocated object is getting the message.

Comment: @pgb Thats the problem, I have gone through the code extensively and i am not releasing any variable thats in the autorelease pool. The only place where i am confused is the "setObject", as i do a [stringWithFormat:] and later release the dictionary, is the error because of this?

Comment: @pgb I tried using NSZombies but it came out clean. NO Problems were detected. :(

Comment: @pgb Thanks, that did it. Although the crash on device usually starts after a couple of days of installing the app on the device. But i guess this is it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a whole bunch of unnecessary work in `+Hello`. My first step at debugging is always to remove unnecessary complexity. Try it like this:

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)Hello {

     NSMutableDictionary *dctONE = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
         @"dsfsdf", @"Object1", @"dsfsdf", @"Object2", nil];

     return dctONE;
}
```

That `NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` method takes a nil-terminated array that goes object, key, object, key. It returns an autoreleased NSMutableDictionary object, which is what you want to be returning.

There are no guarantees in this world, but I can darn near promise you that method won't leak.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the reply but the Hello function i posted here is not the actual one. The [dctONE setObject:] comes in a while loop which is accessing data from a sqlite DB. Leaks was showing a leak on that line, so i jus posted a simplified version.

Comment: @BK: Okay, well, glean what you can from my simplification of your simplification, then. Particularly the use of convenience instantiators that return autoreleased objects.

Comment: @Dan I did as u told and returned a autoreleased Object but still no Luck. "Leaks" is pointing out to [setObject:] as the culprit.

Comment: It's hard to diagnose this when I'm not looking at the real code. You're aware that [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abcd"] an unnecessary construct, right?

Comment: ya i am aware of that. I use this to fill up The dictionary with values returned frm the Db -[stringWithFormat:@"%d",a]; Wait will put the actual code.

Comment: @pgb: in his real code, yes. In the fake code he posted first, he was doing it without any variables to format, which just makes it a waste of typing.

Comment: @Dan it was a unnecessary retain. If not for you i would not have posted the actual code, so thanks